# Appium Screenshots can't capture toast message in an Android native app

Tags: android, screenshot, appium, toast

I'm trying to test the appearance of a toast message in an android native app by taking multiple screenshots after triggering the message, and then try to extract the message by OCR. However my screenshots fail to capture the toast message even if the message is observed on test phone during the test.

In this app the toast message can be triggered by clicking on a button. It appears right after a click and will last for about 1 second. In my code, see below, I take a screenshot right before the click, and then take screenshots after the click every 200 ms for 2 seconds. The message can be seen on the test phone during test but doesn't appear in my screenshots. Could anyone advice how this could happen and how I can overcome this?

Thanks!

```
RRhelper.takeScreenshot(DRIVER, "original");
DRIVER.findElementById("no.ruter.reise.qa:id/search_button").click();
String nameBase="toastDetect";
String name;
for(short i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    name = nameBase + Short.toString(i);
    RRhelper.takeScreenshot(DRIVER, name);
    Thread.sleep(200);
}
```

My helper function for taking screenshot:

```
public static void takeScreenshot(AndroidDriver DRIVER, String name) {
    try {
    File screenshot = DRIVER.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String filename = IMAGE_PATH + name + ".png";
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(filename));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception while saving the file " + e);
}
```

Comment: i am not sure if that should happen, can you debug the execution putting in timestamp to the title of your pics captured and verify.
+ do you see screenshots without toast or are they not even captured?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I got my screenshots withoug toast message. And thanks for the suggestion. After adding time stamp in file name I found that the screenshots are actually taken by intervals of much longer than it should do. It takes about 800 to 1000 millisenconds to take and save one screenshot. What could be the reason for this, could it be processor performance of the computer or the appium server performance? How can I overcome this?

Comment: After further investigation I found that it was the screenshot taking and saving process that takes the most of the time. If I just print out timestamp instead of taking screenshots it takes less then 1 millisecond for one cycle. Again, how can I overcome this?

Comment: I found this solution on the web that uses python: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/968#issuecomment-75641576
It looks like the solution is to start a new thread that will run in parallel so that the timings line up.